# Horizontal overflow sliding panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a animation GUI for web animation and wanted to have the timeline area slide side to side like this: http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/basicUsage.html

I have a start time of 0, so we don't need to slide to negative times, but I would like to be able to zoom in and then slide side to side to see the whole timeline.

I looked into overflow-x: scroll, but that doesn't seem to work as expected.

Here is the issue. Look at this page here: http://imaginarytools.com/. You can see that the timeline goes off the screen to the right, now notice that the background grey color ends just off the screen to the right, so if you scroll to the right there is no grey background behind the ruler.

I have the timeline enclosed like this:

```
<div class="col-md-10 m-0 p-0 timeline-right-panel">
  <div class="col-md-12 scrubberHandle m-0 p-0">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down scrubber-icon"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12  m-0 p-0 timeline-container timeline-container-header">
    <div id="timeSlider" class="col-md-12 m-0 p-0"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12  m-0 p-0 timelineTicks timelineNumbers timelinePositioning"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12  m-0 p-0 timelineTimingPanel"></div>
</div>
```

When you render the page, because of javascript that is run to build the timeline the timeline-header div looks like this when you inspect it:

```
<div class="col-md-12  m-0 p-0 timeline-container timeline-container-header" style="width: 2110px;">
  <div id="timeSlider" class="col-md-12 m-0 p-0"></div>
  <div class="col-md-12  m-0 p-0 timelineTicks timelineNumbers timelinePositioning">
    <span class="minorTick" style="position:absolute;width:2px;height:10px;left:8px;">|</span>
    <span class="minorTick" style="position:absolute;width:2px;height:10px;left:12px;">|</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

In particular notice how it says `style="width: 2110px;"` I have tried all the methods I can find to get the actual width, but all I get is the width of the part with the grey background. The width is controlled by the 500 tick marks on the ruler and the positioning of them which stretches the outer container to fit, but I can't figure out why I can't get the actual width of the container using things like:

```
$(".timeline-container").width()
$(".timeline-container").outerWidth()
```

Is it a problem with bootstrap being involved? I am trying to get the width so I can set the width of the container just under it to match since there are draggable elements that are contained in the space. I would love to make it into a sliding timeline like the one linked from visjs, but as it is I can't seem to get this basic part down.

Any tricks on getting the width of this container?

Comment: I found out it seems to be a bootstrap issue. Removing the bootstrap styling on those elements let me do what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having similar problems, the issue was that Bootstrap wouldn't allow you to get the actual width of the container. I ended up removing bootstrap styling on it, and then setting the width using the same variables I was using to position the tick marks on the ruler.

Also, if you are looking for a good way to scroll your content horizontally, I used this plugin which worked almost seamlessly without needing any other modifications to my JavaScript calculations of mouse position in the container.
http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

There were a couple others like this one: https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane, but the projects seemed a bit dated compared to the one above.